# React redux toolkit. How to stop render If I get the same value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

How to stop render If I get the same value? Should I write some condition for this? Like

```
  if (JSON.stringify(state) === JSON.stringify(payload) {
    return state
  }
return payload
```

**Here is a whole example**

https://codesandbox.io/s/return-redux-toolkit-ersqo?file=/src/redux/slices/slice.js

**here is a part of code**

```
const someSlice = createSlice({
  name: "someSlice",
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    actionSuccess: (state, { payload }) => payload
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the second argument of `useSelector` which is an `equalityFn`.

You can import `shallowEqual` from `react-redux` and pass that as second argument to the `useSelector`. Again this will just do shallow comparisons. You can make use of your own customised function or any library function to do a deep compairson and pass that as second argument to `useSelector`.

I have forked your codesandbox to showcase the `shallowEqual` bit :-

https://codesandbox.io/s/return-redux-toolkit-forked-wtewy